# Matrices as functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, notation

Say I have a matrix where all entries $a_{ij}$ are functions $a_{ij}:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ and the matrix is
$$
\mathbf A(s)=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(s) & a_{12}(s)\\
a_{21}(s) & a_{22}(s)\\
a_{31}(s) & a_{32}(s)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
What is the correct notation for this type of matrix? $\mathbf A:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^{3\times 2}$?

Or if

$$
\mathbf B(s,t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11}(s,t) & b_{12}(s,t)\\
b_{21}(s,t) & b_{22}(s,t)\\
b_{31}(s,t) & b_{32}(s,t)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Here $b_{ij}:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$, is $\mathbf B:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^{3\times 2}$ correct?

Comment: Why do you have the + signs up there?

Comment: @zoli Hi, updated now!

Comment: The typical notation for the space of $m\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ is something like $M_{3\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ (or sometimes $\mathcal{M}_{3\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$).

Comment: You'll never find 2 linear algebra instructors that agree on the notation for a set of matrices.

Comment: @DanielV It is hard enough to find one that uses the same notation consistently.  Finding two who agree is like finding a mated pair of unicorns.

Comment: It is perfectly fine depending on the context. For example, in a analysis context, it is far more commom that $\mathbb R^{3\times 2}$ will denote a triple $(x,y,z)$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are elements of $\mathbb R^{2}$ instead of the space of $3\times 2$ real matrices, which is denoted by $\mathbb{M}_{3\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfect ok to denote $\mathbf{A}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$ and $\mathbf{B}:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$, just as you did.

You can be even more general. Consider some functions $a_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ for $i = 1 \ldots m, j = 1 \ldots n$. Then you can define the matrix function $\mathbf{A}:\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that

$$
\mathbf A(x_1, \ldots, x_k)=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(x_1, \ldots, x_k) \quad \ldots \quad a_{1n}(x_1, \ldots, x_k)\\
\vdots \quad \quad \quad \quad \ddots \quad \quad \quad \quad \vdots\\
a_{m1}(x_1, \ldots, x_k) \quad \ldots \quad a_{mn}(x_1, \ldots, x_k)\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Hi! Updated my post!

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the notation $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 2}$ before (which is, perhaps, more a comment on my lack of exposure than anything else—a quick Googling reveals that it is actually pretty damn common), and can't say that I really like it—it looks too much like $\mathbb{R}^6$, which is something else entirely.  That being said, it is entirely reasonable notation, as long as you are clear about it, i.e. when you use it, make a statement to the effect of "$\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ denotes the space (or set) of $m\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$."

Other notations exist:
$$
M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R}),
\qquad \mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R}),
\qquad M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R}),
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\mathbb{R}^{(m,n)},
$$
for example.  Personally, I prefer something like $M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$, as this remains consistent with, say, $SO_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ for the special orthogonal group, or $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ for the general linear group.

In any event, the moral of the story is to *be clear about your notation.*  When you use a notation that could be potentially ambiguous, or for which alternatives exist, define your terms first and use your definitions consistently.

Comment: As you said, $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is very common. From my experience, in particular, this is *the* notation for the space of matrices $m \times n$.